# gnu make "Removing intermediate files"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rules

```
define compile_c
$(ECHO) "CC $<"
$(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -MD -o $@ $<
@# The following fixes the dependency file.
@# See http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html for details.
@# Regex adjusted from the above to play better with Windows paths, etc.
@$(CP) $(@:.o=.d) $(@:.o=.P); \
  $(SED) -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^.*:  *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
      -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(@:.o=.d) >> $(@:.o=.P); \
  $(RM) -f $(@:.o=.d)
endef

vpath %.c . $(TOP)
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.c $(BUILD)/%.pp
    $(call compile_c)

vpath %.c . $(TOP)

$(BUILD)/%.pp: %.c
    $(ECHO) "PreProcess $<"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -Wp,-C,-dD,-dI -o $@ $<
```

When the build finishes, GNU make says
`Removing intermediate files...` and deletes all the `.pp` files which I do **NOT** want.

Why is it doing this?
How do I stop it?

Comment: The URL you're using for the dependency generation is outdated and may go away at some point.  You should use the correct URL: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you search for "gnu make intermediate files" you'll immediately find the answer as to why it's happening, in the GNU make manual section [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html).

It also tells you how to avoid it: *a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite.*

So, just list your `.pp` files as a prerequisite of some rule, somewhere.  It doesn't have to be a rule that's ever invoked.  You don't give enough of your makefile here for us to provide a complete answer, but it would be something like:

```
all_pps: $(ALL_OBJECTS:.o=.pp)
```

assuming you had a variable `ALL_OBJECTS` containing all your `.o` files.

Comment: If I search for "gnu make intermediate files". I find this post. The post itself guarantees its own success on Google!

Comment: all_pps: $(ALL_OBJECTS:.o=.pp) doesn't work because only the last .pp file is considered!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand that comment @NickHuang, but as far as I do understand it it's not correct.

Comment: What about using `-save-temps`? Wouldn’t that cut in half the number of times the compiler is invoked?

Comment: I'm not sure what `-save-temps` (I presume this is a compiler flag?  It's definitely  not a make flags) has to do with either the question or this answer...?

Answer (score 24):

Since you're using GNU Make, you can make the following adjustment to your Makefile:

```bsh
.PRECIOUS: $(BUILD)/%.pp  # ADD THIS LINE
$(BUILD)/%.pp: %.c
    $(ECHO) "PreProcess $<"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -Wp,-C,-dD,-dI -o $@ $<
```

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) has this to say about `.PRECIOUS` directives:

> The targets which `.PRECIOUS` depends on are given the following special treatment: if make is killed or interrupted during the execution of their recipes, the target is not deleted.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Also, if the target is an intermediate file, it will not be deleted after it is no longer needed, as is normally done.
>
> *[...]*
>
> You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target `.PRECIOUS` to preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns match that file's name.

This has the benefit of not creating an unwanted additional rule. It's also clearer what you're trying to do: keep the precious intermediate files that might be expensive to recreate.

Comment: Personally I would avoid `.PRECIOUS` unless it's _really_ what you want.  It should certainly not be used as a casual replacement for declaring a target as in the answer above.  Consider very carefully what the docs say: if make is killed or interrupted, the target is not deleted.  What if you're compiling a large file and use `^C`?  This interrupts make _and also interrupts your compiler_.  Some compilers will clean up a half-created target, but others will not.  Since the half-created target has a newer timestamp make won't recreate it.  This can be a hard problem to find.

Comment: .SECONDARY is better than .PRECIOUS!

Comment: I'm leaving this up for posterity, but in the intervening years I've come to agree that `.SECONDARY` should be reached for sooner than `.PRECIOUS`. `.PRECIOUS` still has its place when, for instance, you are actively debugging something and _would_ like to keep a partial output on failure.

Answer (score 20):

I think the best solution is to use the `.SECONDARY` special target.  Just add this line:

```
.SECONDARY:
```

Quoting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html):

> `.SECONDARY` with no prerequisites causes all targets to be treated as secondary (i.e., no target is removed because it is considered intermediate).

Why is this better than making the targets prerequisites of a throw-away target?  That's more clutter, and has to be done explicitly for every set of files that might be generated with pattern rules.

Why is this better than `.PRECIOUS`?  That causes files to be retained even if their recipe fails when using `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`.  The latter is important to avoid failing recipes leaving behind bad outputs that are then treated as current by subsequent `make` invocations.  IMO, you always want `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`, but `.PRECIOUS` breaks it.

Comment: Unlike `.PRECIOUS` though, `.SECONDARY` does not work with implicit rules such as `%.o`.

Comment: @syockit `.SECONDARY: $(%.o)` seems to work fine

Comment: @CervEd this would make **all** targets secondary, because `$(%.o)` would evaluate to an empty string. This is just visual noise.

Comment: sorry @MatTheCat I don't follow, can you elaborate? Why would `$(%.o)`  evaluate to an empty string?

Comment: @CervEd `$(%.o)` means “the value of the variable `%.o`”. It is unlikely such a variable will be set, so the value will be an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a detail that finally got PRECIOUS working for me.  The pattern that you give to PRECIOUS has to be *exactly* the pattern that is being used in the rule that creates the intermediate file.  I want to save all files prefixed by moc_.  At first I used
    .PRECIOUS: moc_%
to no avail.  Then I tried
    .PRECIOUS: moc_%.cpp
and this did the trick.